# Isotope: How to display and set opacity values for unmatched items

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-isotope, scaletransform

In my isotope grid I would like to display both matched and unmatched elements without the unmatched elements disappearing. Instead I would like the unmatched elements to have an opacity of 0.7.

On the [Isotope website](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/v1/docs/options.html) they outline the CSS class for the hidden items, so I applied the following to my CSS but it does not work.

```
#main-inner .isotope-hidden, 
.isotope-hidden, 
.isotope-hidden.box {
opacity:0.7 !important;
-webkit-transform:scale(1) !important;
-moz-transform:scale(1) !important;
-ms-transform:scale(1) !important;
-o-transform:scale(1) !important;
transform:scale(1) !important;
}
```

When inspecting in Firebug I cannot see the changes:

I found only one similar question about it ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25916873/jquery-isotope-filtering-fade-unmatched-items-instead-of-hiding)) but there was no any answer.

I found another question about a similar problem ([here](http://tiku.io/questions/5075983/change-isotope-filter-animation-effect)) but the Isotope link does not work anymore and I did not understand anything from the second answer.

My Isotope init:

```
// init Isotope
var $container = $('#main-content').imagesLoaded( function() {
    $container.isotope({
        layoutMode: 'packery',
        packery: {
            columnWidth: '.col-width'
        },
        itemSelector: '.box'
    });
});
// bind filter button click
$('#filter a').click(function(){
    $('#filter .current').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');

    var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    $container.isotope({
        filter: selector,
    });
    return false;
});
```

FIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/h20f38u1/1/

Comment: can you provide us a fiddle so that its easy for us to try out something

Comment: @Cerlin Boss ok, here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/h20f38u1/1/  thank you !

Comment: @IgorLaszlo I didn't remove your fiddle.... I've only created a titled, clickable link: [like this - click it](http://jsfiddle.net/h20f38u1/1/).

Comment: Instead of using a jsfiddle you could use a [stack snippet](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers). They provide mostly the same features but *inside* stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dave Desandro has built a plugin for exactly what you need:

[isotope hide-reveal plugin](http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/drpJK/)

```
$.fn.hideReveal = function( options ) {
options = $.extend({
filter: '*',
hiddenStyle: { opacity: 0.2 },
visibleStyle: { opacity: 1 },
}, options );
this.each( function() {
var $items = $(this).children();
var $visible = $items.filter( options.filter );
var $hidden = $items.not( options.filter );
// reveal visible
$visible.animate( options.visibleStyle );
// hide hidden
$hidden.animate( options.hiddenStyle );
});
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works even more fluid than my "not isotope" solution !

Comment: Just a question : i would like to unblind the clicks on unmatched items, i did it with success but when i select other categories, the unbind function remains effecting the previously unmatched categories... how to return and have effect to the newly unmatched items ? 
What i did :
`var $disabled = $items.not( options.filter ).children();
$disabled.unbind("click");`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see it's not possible to do this smoothly without modifying the way isotope works (although I haven't dug into the source).

You can set the "visible" and "hidden" styles in isotope with options in the `$container.isotope()` call:

```
hiddenStyle: {
    opacity: .7
},
visibleStyle: {
    opacity: 1
},
```

Unfortunately after animating to the hidden style, isotope explicitly sets the a `display: none` style on those divs so you'll need to override that.

```
#main-inner .box {
    display:block !important;
```

It also removes the `opacity` style. You *could* fix that with:

```
#main-inner .box[style*=none] {
    opacity:.7;
}
```

But this is starting to get kind of ugly.

Furthermore, isotope also moves the "visible" items to fill the top left (again with explicit styles), so even if you do this, it's unlikely to be what you're looking for. And on top of that, things will move around strangely as isotope assumes they're invisible when they're not.

http://jsfiddle.net/h20f38u1/2/i

Comment: Thanks ! What you did, i did it already, exactly the same way and this is my problem : in the way you did (and i did), the boxes do not stay in their places... i would like that all boxes (matched and unmatched) stay in their position and only the opacity of the non-matched elements change...

Comment: As I mentioned, that may not be possible without modifying the underlying code. You can override the `display:none` with CSS, but isotope actually changes the `left:` and `top:` properties when it moves things around, and so the original values are lost. I didn't see any options in isotope to tell it not to do this: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/options.html

Comment: What do you mean modifying the underlying code ? You mean to change the isotope script ? There is no problem if i must change it but a question remains : where and how...

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean, but without reading and understanding the code it's difficult to speculate. You could search for "left" and/or "top" and see where it's setting the style. You may need to somehow detect the difference between the initial layout and filtered layout at that point so that the initial one will work, etc... Or maybe you should rethink and not use isotopes filtering at all... Since you don't need to re-lay out anything you could just apply the relevant opacity to the relevant divs directly for example

Comment: Yes, i did that too, i beautified and checked out the codes but it is too complicated for my jquery knowledge. I found an alternative solution for my problem, i will put it as an answer, not so nice but if someone look for the same effect, it will give an idea... Thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

So, if someone would like the same effect and nothing has found, i have a solution which is not so nice but shows what i wanted...

1) First i desabled the data-filter in the filter menu init code to stop filtering :

```
// bind filter button click
$('#filter a').click(function(){
    $('#filter .current').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');

    //var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    //$container.isotope({
        //filter: selector,
    //});
    return false;
});
```

2) I added classes to the menu filter links

```
<div id="filter">
    <a class="cat1" href="#" data-filter=".category1">Category1</a>
    <a class="cat2" href="#" data-filter=".category2">Category2</a>
    <a class="cat3" href="#" data-filter=".category3">Category3</a>
    <a class="cat-all current" href="#" data-filter="*">All</a>
</div>
```

3) I added a cover on each box which will play the opacity animation and i gave it a transparent opacity :

```
.highlight {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:#000000;
    opacity:0;
}
```

4) I animated the cover (.highlight) with jquery :

```
$('#filter .cat1').click(function(){
    $('#main-inner div .highlight').not('#main-inner .category1 .hightlight' ).animate({ 'opacity':'1' },800);
    $('.category1 .highlight').animate({'opacity':'0'},800);
});
$('#filter .cat2').click(function(){
    $('#main-inner div .highlight').not('#main-inner .category2 .hightlight' ).animate({ 'opacity':'1' },800);
    $('.category2 .highlight').animate({'opacity':'0'},800);
});
$('#filter .cat3').click(function(){
    $('#main-inner div .highlight').not('#main-inner .category3 .hightlight' ).animate({ 'opacity':'1' },800);
    $('.category3 .highlight').animate({'opacity':'0'},800);
});
$('#filter .cat-all').click(function(){
    $('.highlight').animate({'opacity':'0'},800);
});
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/h20f38u1/5/

Comment: You should try this [isotope hide-reveal plugin](http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/drpJK/)

Comment: @Macsupport - this is exactly what i am looking for... write it in an answer and i will accept it as the best solution !!! :)